# Start node app at container start with Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm learning a bit of Docker and at best of what you think, just find a little problem and solve it.

You have my image with all the requirements to run a system in nodejs and that has 2 parts, the frontend and the backend.

At the moment I can only run them together and only run the startup commands manually from the console.

My yml file:

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  soporte:
    build:
      context: './soporte/'
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "8080:8080"
    container_name: soporte
```

My DockerFile is the following:

```
FROM imagensoportep

RUN mkdir -p /home/soporte

COPY soporte /home/soporte

WORKDIR /home/soporte/backend

RUN cd /home/soporte/backend

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build

RUN npm install -g pm2

RUN pm2 start dist/server.js --name soporte-backend

WORKDIR /home/soporte/frontend

RUN cd /home/soporte/frontend

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build

RUN pm2 start server.js --name soporte-frontend

RUN pm2 save

EXPOSE 3000
EXPOSE 8080
```

i need start frontend/server.js and backend/dist/server.js at same time at start container?

Comment: The standard pattern is to start these parts in two separate containers.  Potentially they have two different images, if their source code is substantially different (one is Express-based and one is React-based, for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First,** it's better to separate different components into different containers. But this is not the key item of your problem here, the main item here is you did not catch the difference of [RUN](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run) VS. [ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) VS. [CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd):

A key difference here is, refers to [this](https://aboullaite.me/dockerfile-run-vs-cmd-vs-entrypoint/):

> **RUN** executes the command(s) that you give in a new layer and creates a new image. This is mainly used for installing a new package.
>
> **CMD** is the default command to be run by the entrypoint. It sets default command and/or parameters, however, we can overwrite those commands or pass in and bypass the default parameters from the command line when docker runs
>
> **ENTRYPOINT** is the program to run the given command. It is used when yo want to run a container as an executable.

In a word, `RUN` is just used to form a image layer when build a docker image, not used for `docker run`. If you want to start any service when run the container, you should put it `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD`.

**Finally,** if you need to run more than one service within a container, you can accomplish this in a few different ways:

> - Put all of your commands in a wrapper script, complete with testing and debugging information. Run the wrapper script as your CMD
> - If you have one main process that needs to start first and stay running but you temporarily need to run some other processes (perhaps to interact with the main process) then you can use bash’s job control to facilitate that.
> - Use a process manager like supervisord. This is a moderately heavy-weight approach that requires you to package supervisord and its configuration in your image (or base your image on one that includes supervisord), along with the different applications it manages. Then you start supervisord, which manages your processes for you.

Details refers to [Run multiple services in a container](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/).